# "This Action Won't Work on Multiple Selections" - VBA to deselect anything that would be causing the issue?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of Excel models (all identical) that are a standard template. The model has about a dozen macros within it. For some reason, some of these models run into an error whereby I can no longer add a new sheet nor can I paste (any type -- regular, values, etc) into another blank workbook.

I have no idea what is causing this. Instead of trying to troubleshoot the entire thing, I am curious if there is some VBA I could run that would go through the entire workbook and deselect whatever is causing the error.

Comment: How would you expect it to identify the item causing the issue in order to *deselect* it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.